# Interpreting DHCP related message from rsyslog

Tags: amazon-ec2, dhcp, log-files, rsyslog

In **/var/log/messages** from an EC2 instance there are a lot of lines such as:

```
<date/timestamp> ip-<IP_HERE> ec2net: [get_meta] Trying to get http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/MAC_ADDR/local-ipv4s
<date/timestamp> ip-<IP_HERE> ec2net: [rewrite_aliases] Rewriting aliases of eth0
<date/timestamp> ip-<IP_HERE> dhclient[2187]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 112321ms.
<date/timestamp> ip-<IP_HERE> dhclient[2187]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 111231ms.
....
and more XMT: Solicit messages (hundreds more)
```

Why would there be hundreds of these solicit messages, and what does `XMT: Solicit on eth0`mean? How should I interpret this?

Is this simply the log of a DHCP request (or many requests)? I haven't seen "XMT" previously.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An XMT Solicit is basically a DHCPv6 (IPv6 DHCP) request. If you're not using IPv6 at all disable it because your instance is trying to request an IPv6-IP.

The problem seems to be that your instance is running an older version of dhclient which is logging with log-level "normal".
Normally dhclient should only log from the log-level "warning" and above.

You could also disable logging messages for dclient and ec2net by adding this code

```
:programname,isequal,"dhclient"  ~
:programname,isequal,"ec2net"    ~
```

to a new file (e.g. "dhclient") under /etc/rsyslog.d/.

See more here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCPv6#Example

Answer (score 0):

You can hide all messages from dhclient by creating a file in `/etc/rsyslog.d/` with the extension of .conf, and then adding the more current rsyslog syntax as such:

```
echo "if $programname == "dhclient" then stop" > /etc/rsyslog.d/dhclient.conf
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

If you try and do what the other answer says you'll get
`Aug  9 19:53:27 home rsyslogd: warning: ~ action is deprecated, consider using the 'stop' statement instead [v8.24.0-41.amzn2.2.1 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2307 ]`